# Facing issue with magento2 upgrade to latest version with composer update

Tags: nginx, permissions, composer-php, magento2, upgrade

I am facing an issue, when I want to update my Magento 2 store version to the latest version, running `composer update`, throw this error:

> Cannot create cache directory
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/sgn/repo/https---repo.magento.com/, or directory
>   is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create cache
>   directory
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/sgn/repo/https---composer.amasty.com-community/,
>   or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create
>   cache directory
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/sgn/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or
>   directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache Cannot create
>   cache directory /usr/share/nginx/html/sgn/files/, or directory is not
>   writable. Proceeding without cache Loading composer repositories with
>   package information   [RuntimeException]
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/sgn/vcs does not exist and could not be created.

I took contact with support, but they refuse to give permission to `/usr/share/nginx/html/sgn/vcg` as the project is on shared host.

I just want to update my Magento 2 store to latest version

Comment: Are you having any luck with M2 on shared? This is a bit funny thing to do. You have to have a dedicated user for running M2, but apparently running commands in a directory owned by `nginx`.

Comment: so, you don't have solution for this :( ,but if it needs dedicated server, than how it was worked before this issue? @DanilaVershinin